# Unable to have li items take all space within ul

Tags: html, css

Provided is the following jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rPJ49/1/

I'm trying to have all the li-items inside the ul-list take a % of space so that in the end they take all space. Between every li-item there should be a margin of .xx%, expect the last child.

So what's wrong with this example? If you resize the panel horizontally, you'll see 1px(?) is not filled at the most right.

See (bad):
[image]

See (good):
[image]

All items have a % width, see:

```
.items li
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: .25%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 16.41666666666667%;
}

.items li:last-child
{
    margin-right: 0%;
    width: 16.66666666666667%;
}


Which would lead to: 
5 * 16,41666666666667  = 82,08333333333335%
5 * .25%               = 1.25%
1 * 16,66666666666667  = 16,66666666666667%
Adding them
100%
```

Any ideas how to solve or for a better way to create multi line li's that take 100% height and together 100% width (with a margin)?

Comment: Are `.outerContainer`, `.innerContainer` and `.element` required ? (if I've got the way to remove it)

Comment: It seems that floating right the :last-child doesn't fix the problem...

Comment: It's from an article. It's supposed to enable li-items to take 100% height and be multi line. This is very hard to achieve without this approach. So yes, i think they're required.

Comment: @MauricePerry; i tried float: right, and it didn't work :(

Comment: My only problem is this **transparent** space between elements... Still searching.

Comment: @Velth finally got it, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The trick, which I learned from the fantastic [Harry Roberts](http://csswizardry.com), is to use `display: table` on the container and `display: table-cell` on the list items. Table cells stretch take up the full width of the container, depending on how many there are.

His original demo didn't have margins in between the items, but I've forked it and made a new version with the margins:

http://jsfiddle.net/zfSt4/400/

Comment: I'm also doing some tries with this trick. Your example won't exactly work with multiline elements (which is required by OP).

Answer (score 2):

I finally got a solution...

Here's your new (simpler) structure :

```
<div class="items">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="element">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="mini">Mini's</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <!-- ... -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS :

```
.items
{
    border: 3px solid rgba(235, 235, 235, 0.6);
}

.items ul
{
    width: 100%;
    display: table;            /* consider your list as a table */
    table-layout: fixed;       /* fix equal width on every column */
}

.items li
{
    display: table-cell;       /* consider your element as a table cell */
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.items li + li
{
    padding-left: 3px;         /* add the transparent space between elements */
}

.items li .element
{
    display: table;            /* use the multiline trick */
    float: left;               /* IMPORTANT : avoid crasy margins */
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(235, 235, 235, 0.6);
}

.items li .element a
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'nexa_lightregular';
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 60%;
}
```

[**Updated JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/rPJ49/3/)

### EDIT I:

It seems to have a browser issue with percent calculation (see [here](http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/display-table-where-is-this-extra-pixel-coming-from/) for details).
Here's a workaround : add a one pixel `box-shadow` on the right side of the last element to hide this extra pixel margin :

```
.items li:last-child
{
    box-shadow: 1px 0 rgba(235, 235, 235, 0.6);
}
```

### EDIT II:

Finally, that wasn't a good idea x) You'll have this additionnal `box-shadow` even when there's no extra pixel, and it'll be visible (because of your semi-transparent background).

Instead, play on the width to remove the extra pixel :

```
.items {
    width: 90.05%; /* instead of 90% */
}
```

[**Updated JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/rPJ49/7/)

Comment: Seems to work really nice, altho.. when you set a "fixed" width %, then the same problem occurs, see: http://jsfiddle.net/rPJ49/5/

Comment: Ow... [It seems to be a Chrome bug](http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/display-table-where-is-this-extra-pixel-coming-from/) with `display: table` and `vertical-align: middle`

Comment: It has to do something to do rounding the %'s in pixels, that's my guess. Altho you hinted for a a simpler solution; it doesn't bring me really further than my begin post. My website has to be responsive, on resizing an extra unwanted pixel appears. I could go with media queries, but I'm not sure mhhh..

Comment: Will you use transparency as here ? Without, there are several ways to hide the gap, like my edit #2

Comment: Yes I do see transparency. In your last edit, even if you resize the screen horizontally you'll see the first and second menu alter the last pixel of transparency. Sometimes they both have a pixel of transparency.

Answer (score 1):

This will keep your last li from having a right margin, and is more supported that using :last-child
I haven't tested this, but I use this method personally

```
.items li
{
   /* apply general styles + float : right */
}

.items li + li
{
   /* apply your margin-right + float : inherit */
}
```